# Reproducing Difference operation from QGIS in pure Python?

Tags: python, geojson

I have two GeoJSON files and I want to make the difference of those two layers, QGIS does it really well, but I need to do it in pure Python 2.7.

Anyone know how to do it ?

[image: the operation "difference"]

Answer (score 1):

Geopandas has a set operations built in (http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html).